# How to create a list based on a number condition in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following list in Python

```
l = [1,2,1,1,2,4,5,5,6,6,7,8,8,9,9]
```

And the intention is create a new list to turn all numbers in `l <= 5` into 0 and all `l>5` into 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use list comprehension for this

```
[int(item > 5) for item in l]
```

Comment: Glad I could help!